# Possible to call all employees calendars in Power BI using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, powerbi

With our organization, we use Office 365. We would like to use all employees calendars to visualize capacity in Power BI.

Within Power BI (using get data -> OData feed) I can retrieve one of my colleague's calendar events by calling Microsoft Graph with the following command:

```
/v1.0/users/[email]/calendar/events
```

Is it also possible to load the events of all employees calendars directly into Power BI using Microsoft Graph?

(All users can be called via `/v1.0/users`, but even better: all relevant users can be called via a group we already have: `/v1.0/groups/[group_id]/members`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a supported scenario. You would need to separately collect the events from each calendar under each user, stitch them together, and store the result. Assuming you have a small enough organization to avoid running into the API's throtting thresholds, it might be doable. That said, keeping your data in sync with all of those calendars over time will present additional challenges.